# How can I add an element to a header in Joomla?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I got a website on Joomla. I want to add three PNG files right here:

[image: photo where i want to put png files]

How can I do that? How can I edit HTML in Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new position in your template.
P.S. especially for joomla there is a section: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much ! And how can i add a new position to my template ?

Comment: can you show me positions of your template? Or find this position from positions list

Comment: You mean the modules ?

Comment: Add a new module from your images in this position